# I got the following problem when trying to install xgboost using pip, Files/Directories not found, could anyone help on that?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, xgboost

I have Python 3.8 32-bit, when I try to install xgboost using pip, I got the following message, does anyone know how to resolve it?

ERROR: Files/directories not found in C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\xgboost\pip-egg-info

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share the complete error message, not just part of it

Comment: ERROR: Files/directories not found in C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\xgboost\pip-egg-info

this is the complete error message

Comment: Have you tried running `pip install` from the command line?

Comment: Are you using Conda? Please share some information on your environment, as well as the command(s) used.

Comment: I tried pip install , then get this error. I’m using windows system, 32digit. Yes, I tried Conda too, did not work